# Create a custom regex

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex that can check for the following:

- can have either `http` or `https`
- might have `www` or not
- must have `steamcommunity`, `.com`
- must have either `id` or `profiles` followed by numbers or text

  http://steamcommunity.com/id/rasmusvejby/
  http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198040893433

Also it should be said that if it contains ID it should check if there are text, and if it contains profiles I should check for numbers.

Comment: @nhouser9 I don't know where to start. That is pretty much, what i am looking for, how to start.

Comment: Then you should be searching on Google for tutorials on regex, not just asking StackOverflow to do your work for you. We'll help you with specific issues, but are not here to simply write your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Decription

Given your sample text...

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/rasmusvejby/
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198040893433
```

...this Regex...

```
^https?://(?:www\.)?steamcommunity\.com/(id/([^/\s]*)|profiles/([^/\s]*))
```

...will do the following

1. validate the url contains `steamcommunity.com`
2. matches with or without the leading `www`
3. Allows `http` or `https`
4. captures the id or profile portion of the url
5. captures the string for the id or profile

Capture Groups

- Group 0 gets the full string
- Group 1 gets the (ID or Profiles) and the associated value
- Group 2 gets just the value of the ID
- Group 3 gets just the value of the Profile

## Example

Sample matches

```
[0][0] = http://steamcommunity.com/id/rasmusvejby
[0][1] = id/rasmusvejby
[0][2] = rasmusvejby
[0][3] = 

[1][0] = http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198040893433
[1][1] = profiles/76561198040893433
[1][2] = 
[1][3] = 76561198040893433
```

## Explanation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  http                    'http'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  s?                       with or without 's'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ://                      '://'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    www                      'www'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  steamcommunity           'steamcommunity'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  com/                     'com/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    id/                      'id/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^/\s]*                  any character except: '/', whitespace
                               (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    profiles/                'profiles/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^/\s]*                  any character except: '/', whitespace
                               (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```