# Check if valid steam profile url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to make a regex that checks if the url a user is posting, are valid.

I have created the following regex:

`/https?\:\/steamcommunity\/.com\/profiles|id\/[a-zA-Z0-9]/`

But that isn't working. Is there a regex master, here that can tell me what i am doing wrong?

The links i am trying to validate are looking like:

> https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198009610232/
>   https://steamcommunity.com/id/rasmusvejby/

**ANSWERE**

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?steamcommunity\.com\/(?:profiles|id)\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
```

Comment: This is basically the same as [Create a custom regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37016180/4642212), but this time with an attempted solution.

Comment: Show us some positive and negative matches.  By the way, try using [Regex101](www.regex101.com) .

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Using that it tells me " This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string. "

Comment: Are you looking for a true/false answer or are you also trying to extract a portion of your URL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True/Falls. Since i need it in my form. So that if it is valid, it cann be submitted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?steamcommunity\.com\/(?:profiles|id)\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

See this demo:

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZ1xF9/1)

The "g" modifier is just so you can see it test it in different strings, but you probably dont need it.

Comment: lbarros That was it! Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad I could help. To get the details on the regex, see the explanation part on the demo I post it.

Comment: lbarros i will! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to this question will also match this url for example:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/profile/thisisimpossible
```

I am using the following regex to prevent non  numeric characters when the id is prepended by profile/ rather than id/. Not necessarily prettier but it does the job.

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?steamcommunity\.com\/(?:profiles\/[0-9]{17}|id\/[a-zA-Z0-9].*)$
```